# this javascript is not working in chrome but works in ie

Tags: javascript

```
<script language="javascript">


function switchScreen(v)
{

if(v=='d')
{
    mf.rows="0,*";
    window.frames.topFrame.location='blank.htm';

}
else
{
    mf.rows="*,0";
    window.frames.topFrame.location='http://sample.htm';


}


}



</script>


<frameset name="mf" id="mainFrame" rows="*,0" frameborder=no framespacing=0>
<frame name='topFrame' id="tp" src='http://sample.htm/' scrolling="no" frameborder=0 noresize marginheight=0 marginwidth=0>
<frame name='bottomFrame' id="bp" src='Main.html' scrolling="no" frameborder=0 noresize  marginheight=0 marginwidth=0>
</frameset>
```

The function is called from within the bottom frame

Comment: in what way is it not working? is it throwing a JS error? please provide more details.

Comment: (-1) please provide a proper description of the problem and the error messages that pop up.

Comment: no error. In ie bottom frame becomes 100% when called switchScreen('d') . in chrome it doesn't

Comment: I'm hoping this is legacy code, who still codes for frames? :)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `mf` will be available in Internet Explorer only, because that browser has the "feature" of adding all DOM elements with a name to the `window` object.

Add

```
mf = document.getElementById("mainFrame");
```

to the top of the script and it will work.

By the way, to see JavaScript errors in Chrome, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>J</kbd> and then the "Console" tab. Every browser has a JavaScript error console, which should always be the first port of call when something doesn't work; it's just a bit hidden sometimes.

Comment: it doesn't work. i tried javascript console. this is what i get Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL http://205.177.170.156/test/bin-release/index.htm from frame with URL http://sample.com/. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

Comment: @Vivek that's a new error. Try `.src` instead of `location`, e.g. `window.frames.topFrame.src ="..."` you can't modify a document that's not on your domain.

Comment: i found the issue. it was because the second frame was using a location in a different domain. thanks a lot

Comment: "Every browser has a JavaScript error console" - I think you'll find the one in IE6 & IE7 to be pretty lousy! ;-) unless of course you install the web developer toolbar, debug bar or similar.  That said, indeed the console is the first place to check (when available).